# AsyncTask in Service - overkill?

Tags: android

Im currently doing some network related stuff,

```
public void postData() {

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xx.xx.php");

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

in an asynctask, which i am executing from a service.

What i would like to know is if its enough to run the network methods directly in the service? Because AFAIK it doesnt run on the UI thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IntentService` has its own thread and you don't need the `AsyncTask` but a normal `Service` runs on the UI thread and you need to move the operations that take a long time to another thread(like using the `AsyncTask`). The `Service` running on the main UI thread is stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. What would be the main difference between a "regular" service and an intentservice?

Comment: @Johan You could look at an `IntentService` as a `Service` to which you send various request to be handled out of the main thread(like, for example, a request to download a photo from an address(you could send to that `IntentService` many requests)).  You would use a `Service` for operation that require more time to complete(for example, a mp3 player playing your favorite song).

Comment: Another nice thing about them is that they die as soon as they finish their job.

Comment: I see. In my case my service uses an onLocationChanged listener from the gps and sends the positions to my webservice using an asynctask. Does this sound like an ok solution in this case?

Comment: @Johan It's ok, I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Just keep the network stuff in that `AsyncTask` so the user will be happy using your app :)

Comment: Just a note. You don't have to put your `onLocationChanged` listener in a separate thread. The listener itself doesn't block the main thread. However if it suits your case more, you're ok to do it

Comment: @MichałK Thanks, but since i want it to "listen" in all of my activities, I figured that i might as well put it there. Or is there a better way to make it global?

Comment: I think it's fine:) Just pay attention to what you do with a Service, it's quite prone to leaks afaik.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.

So t's not an overkill unless you use `IntentService`